# mocking string.equalsIgnoreCase(String) using java mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I am finding a null pointer exception while testing a string with other string.
I have a string variable (say str_var) which i am checking in a condition to see whether it equals to (say "abc" perform one step and if not perform otherwise.

```
if (str_var.equalsIgnoreCase("abc") {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

while testing this code with mockito i am finding str_var null resulting a null pointer exception.

need some inputs on how to make the test success.

Comment: Can you paste the code to show how str_var is initialized?

Comment: So is your problem that `str_val` is null and it is not supposed to be, or is it that you don't know how to check its value without throwing a NPE?

Comment: Don't try to mock the behavior of `String`: just use a real `String`. If you're getting a NPE, that's because you're not setting `str_var` to a non-null value, which has nothing to do with mockito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
"abc".equalsIgnoreCase(str_var)
```

It will help to avoid the `NullPointerException`

Comment: From the question I understand that OP want / expect to test about the str_var is null. If I am not wrong I think he will want to go to the else part with the str_val null

Comment: True, I am just highlighting that. I think it would be good to explore why there is a null in the first place and see if there is a better and more elegant solution.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. Of course there can be better solution

Comment: this string is a property fetched from spring @Value annotation. I am not hard coding the value in the code. But yes the above solution solved the issue of NPE.